# Execute multiple T-SQL statements

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is not allowing me to execute all the index creation statements. If my first index creation statement failed, it does not move to the next line.

Suppose I am creating below three indexes. My first index fails to get created, since its already present.

In this scenario, SQL Server does not move to the next line and continue execution.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LWF_Steps_WFG] ON [dbo].[LW_Steps] ([CONID]);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LWF_Con_ACS] ON [dbo].[LWF_Config] ([MasterID]);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Config] ON [dbo].[LWF_Config] ([CONFIGID]);
```

Is there any way, if my first index statement fails, to tell SQL Server to move on to the next statement?

Comment: Put `GO` between them

Comment: Use `TRY...CATCH` or set `XACT_ABORT` to `OFF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether the index exists before creating:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM sys.indexes  WHERE name='IX_LWF_Steps_WFG' 
    AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[LW_Steps]'))
  begin
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LWF_Steps_WFG] ON [dbo].[LW_Steps] ([CONID]);
  end
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Dale said, you should use GO between commands:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LWF_Steps_WFG] ON [dbo].[LW_Steps] ([CONID]);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_LWF_Con_ACS] ON [dbo].[LWF_Config] ([MasterID]);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Config] ON [dbo].[LWF_Config] ([CONFIGID]);
GO
```